# Copying user account and all settings?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, bashrc

I recently performed a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.04 and tried to create the username that I wanted to create "Sean.Ochoa" (without the quotes), but it wouldn't let me... saying something about the symbols (though the error was cut off due to display issues).  To get around it, I created a user account "sean" and used that.  It worked, but due to authentication issues on the corporate network where I work, it makes my life a whole lot easier if I can just use the login "Sean.Ochoa".  So, I created a new login and then copied over the home folder from the initial login.  I've also run chown and chmod o+rwx recursively on all files in the new user's home dir.

Now I'm experiencing some problems while logged in as the new user.

1. The bash login screen doesn't have any coloring to it.
2. The bash shell doesn't do any tab completion.
3. The "user@host:dir$" is just "$" without the user@host:dir.

I'm confused by these two things.  Could someone tell me how to fix these issues?

Comment: `o+rwx` is risky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. The bash login screen doesn't have any coloring to it.

`bash` does not have a "login screen".

> 2. The bash shell doesn't do any tab completion.
> 3. The "user@host:dir$" is just "$" without the user@host:dir.

This usually means you are in `sh`, not `bash`. Use `chsh` to change your login shell.

*(The `user@host:dir$` and `$` things are called "prompts", by the way.)*

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you copy EVERTTHING including the hidden files that start with a "." You're probably missing `.bashrc` or one of its equivalent.